# Move content from one git repository to another?

Tags: git

I have a current git repository at xp-dev.com, lets call it A. Now I have created a new project at xp-dev.com which has its own git repository, lets call it B. Now, A have a lot of committed code in it, and I would like to move all content of A including commit-history to B. And B is empty, it is basically just an initialized repository with no checked-in code.

How do I do this? I have tried to solve it myself but it seems almost impossible to just say "push content of A into B"...

Please, help me out, I spent several hours on this last night when I could have done more productive things :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm new to git and I don't know about the particulars of xp-dev.com, but you should be able to do it with something like this.

First, clone and *mirror* the original repository

```
git clone --mirror orig-host:A
```

Then push it up to its new home (providing the repo is already created)

```
cd A
git push --mirror new-host:B
```

Note: this is destructive to the new repository. It might be worth trying this offline first.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following sequence:

```
git clone orig-host:repo
cd repo
git remote add target dest-host:repo
git push target master
# repeat the last command for every unmerged branch
```

Comment: Adding new remote isn't necessary.

Comment: It is if you want to maintain a mirror.

Comment: Indeed. The --mirror version is destructive on the target (meaning, it will remove all branches that aren't in your local repository), but this doesn't matter in this case. Oh, a shorter way to push all the branches to another repo would be `git push tmp $(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)")`. This will push tags as well.